# Select photo from gallery android

Tags: android, imageview, image-gallery

I'm trying to build an app that contains an ImageView .If I click it ,the gallery shows up so I can select a picture for the imageView.
My Xml is so simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"/>
<LinearLayout>
```

and here's my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView img;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    setContentView(R.layout.cam);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Contact Image"),1);
        }
    });

 }
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resCode, Intent data){
    if(resCode==RESULT_OK){
        if(reqCode==1){
            img.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on right way, just change few things.

This will open your gallery:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Next step implement onActivityResult callback. It's simple too:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

Hope this will help u:)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Magical Take Photo library.**
You have the posibility of select picture or take photo with this library, ad the posibility of resize and change the quality of the photo :D

**1. try with compile in gradle**

```
 compile 'com.frosquivel:magicaltakephoto:1.0'
```

**2. You need this permission in your manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

**3. instance the class like this**

// "this" is the current activity param

```
MagicalTakePhoto magicalTakePhoto =  new MagicalTakePhoto(this,ANY_INTEGER_0_TO_4000_FOR_QUALITY);
```

**4. if you need to take picture use the method**

```
magicalTakePhoto.takePhoto("my_photo_name");
```

**5. if you need to select picture in device, try with the method:**

```
 magicalTakePhoto.selectedPicture("my_header_name");
```

**6. You need to override the method onActivityResult of the activity or fragment like this:**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        magicalTakePhoto.resultPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //example to get photo
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(magicalTakePhoto.getMyPhoto());
    }
```

Note: Only with this Library you can take and select picture in the device, this use a min API 15.